# Get more than 2000 with SOAP and PHP

Tags: soql, soap, limits, php

I'm trying to return more than 2000 records, I haven't seen any answers for people using PHP and SOAP. Any recommendations? My query is simply:

```
 SELECT
      ID, Name
    FROM
      Contact
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SOAP API can return up to 2000 records at a time. If there are more records, then you will also be returned a QueryLocator which you can then use to do QueryMore call. You need to repeat the QueryMore multiple times until you get everything. See http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_querymore.htm

Comment: My problem is that it's pretty slow. I'm going through 135k contacts. It takes around 30 seconds which in browser time is an eternity

Comment: Why do you need to retrieve so many contacts? Can you modify the query to get less records or implement pagination?

Comment: can't imagine there's a useful UI that shows all 135k contacts in one go.

Comment: What's your batch size? https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_changing_batch_size.htm might help you save on the roundtrips but your memory usage will go up because the incoming message will grow accordingly. Or read about Bulk API maybe?